# How to plot a graph from data

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have `data1` and `data2`, where `data1` is frequencies and `data2` is periods.

I need to plot frequency vs. period. How can I do it?

```
data1 = {3.25806, 3.30944, 3.36129, 3.40927, 3.45363, 3.49455, 3.5327, 
  3.56761, 3.6001, 3.63016, 3.65791, 3.68351, 3.70714, 3.72898, 
  3.74925, 3.76776, 3.78501, 3.80084, 3.81548, 3.82892, 3.84143, 
  3.85282, 3.86339, 3.87312, 3.88199, 3.89029, 3.89803, 3.90488, 
  3.91144, 3.91727, 3.92265, 3.92788, 3.93236, 3.9367, 3.94042, 
  3.94415, 3.94758, 3.95116, 3.95257, 3.9557, 3.95883, 3.9604, 
  3.96197, 3.96511, 3.96511, 3.96825, 3.96825, 3.97141, 3.97141, 
  3.97141, 3.97456, 3.97456, 3.97456, 3.97614, 3.97772, 3.97772, 
  3.97772, 3.97931, 3.97931, 3.97931, 3.9889, 3.98089, 3.98089, 
  3.98089, 3.98248, 3.98248, 3.98089, 3.98248, 3.98406, 3.98248, 
  3.98248, 3.98406, 3.98248, 3.98406, 3.98406, 3.98406, 3.98406, 
  3.98406, 3.98406, 3.98406, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98406, 
  3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98406, 
  3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 
  3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 
  3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 
  3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 
  3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 
  3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98565, 3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 
  3.98406, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565, 3.98565}

data2 = {0.3069, 0.3022, 0.2975, 0.2933, 0.2896, 0.2862, 0.2831, 0.2803, 
  0.2778, 0.2755, 0.2734, 0.2715, 0.2697, 0.2682, 0.2667, 0.2654, 
  0.2642, 0.2631, 0.2621, 0.2612, 0.2603, 0.2596, 0.2588, 0.2582, 
  0.2576, 0.2571, 0.2565, 0.2561, 0.2557, 0.2553, 0.2549, 0.2546, 
  0.2543, 0.254, 0.2538, 0.2535, 0.2533, 0.2531, 0.253, 0.2528, 
  0.2526, 0.2525, 0.2524, 0.2522, 0.2522, 0.252, 0.252, 0.2518, 
  0.2518, 0.2518, 0.2516, 0.2516, 0.2516, 0.2515, 0.2514, 0.2514, 
  0.2514, 0.2513, 0.2513, 0.2513, 0.2507, 0.2512, 0.2512, 0.2512, 
  0.2511, 0.2511, 0.2512, 0.2511, 0.251, 0.2511, 0.2511, 0.251, 
  0.2511, 0.251, 0.251, 0.251, 0.251, 0.251, 0.251, 0.251, 0.251, 
  0.2509, 0.251, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 
  0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 
  0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 
  0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 
  0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 
  0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 
  0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 
  0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 
  0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 
  0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 
  0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 
  0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 
  0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 
  0.2509, 0.2509, 0.251, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 0.2509, 
  0.2509}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Transpose@{data2, data1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"period", "frequency"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.01]}]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** *after acceptance*:

A whole bunch of options:

```
ListPlot[Transpose@{data2, data1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "Title of the plot", 
 FrameLabel -> {"period", "frequency"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black}, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Point[Transpose@{data2, data1}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
data=Transpose[{data2,data1}];
ListLinePlot[data,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]